# Why HTML5 tags are made semantic?

Tags: css, html

I am working on HTML5 and i came across various HTML5 semantic tags like `<article> <section> <aside> <nav> <header> <footer> <audio> <video> <source> <track> <embed> <canvas>` etc.

I would like to what exactly is the advantage of using these semantic tags. is it for fast loading or any other feature?

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Semantics have been the whole point of HTML right from the very beginning. But based on the question "is it for fast loading", it would seem that you don't really understand what the word "semantic" means. To that end, the question here appears to be "what does 'semantic' mean?" which would be off-topic for SO.

Comment: see http://www.webmechanix.com/advantages-of-html5-and-semantic-markup `Unfortunately, there is no answer and the benefits of HTML5 varies from project to project. For example, if most of a sites web traffic comes from browsers such as older browsers like Internet Explorer 7/8 then it might not be the best approach to use. However, if the majority of site traffic is a tech savvy audience that uses modern browsers like Chrome, Safari and Firefox you should be embracing these new technologies to not only enhance their browsing experiences but also set a pace for other late adopters to follow.`

Comment: @BoltClock i just want to know, say for example the difference between <div class="footer"> </div> and <footer> </footer> . is it just to convey the meaning?

Comment: @Shareer1: Yes, that's exactly what "semantic" means. Nothing to do with performance.

Comment: @Shareer1 the content of HTML tags is opaque to the computers that parse them. When every tag is a `<div>` the computer can’t be expected to have a clue what is on the page. They don’t know that `<div class="footer"> is a footer. However, when you categorize your content into meaningful tags the computer can now understand what types are content are what and use that information accordingly, for example when presenting the page to blind people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Advantages of semantic tags

- It's easier for computers to understand what content is in your document and how it is structured. For example, having article tags would make it easier for a tool like Safari Reader or Readability to find the content of a blog post.
- Screen readers will also have more information about what is on the page. This is incredibly useful for vision impaired users, especially since they can more easily jump to navigation controls and article contents while skipping less important content.
- It's easier for developers to logically sort out parts of HTML documents, and easier to semantically add CSS styles around your HTML.

Answer (score 5):

It's to accurately describe the content of the tag.

For example this means when Google (or any search bot) crawls a page, it can more accurately dissect it and assign relevance scores to the various bits of content.

Wikipedia has a [nice simple definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML):

> Semantic HTML is the use of HTML markup to reinforce the semantics, or meaning, of the information in webpages rather than merely to define its presentation or look. Semantic HTML is processed by regular web browsers as well as by many other user agents. CSS is used to suggest its presentation to human users.

So whether a browser takes special action upon tags like `audio` and `video` is purely up to the developer of the browser rendering engine, but they are there to be used.